# Xaml designer in windows phone 8.0 (cannot create an instance of my custom control)

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm creating a custom control for windows phone 8, in this control I use a class from a Windows Runtime Component (.winmd).

The problem is in the xaml designr my custom control not appear, but the control works fine in rut mode.

(As I mentioned above this is in design time (Xaml designer)) :

"Cannot create instance of MyControl", and the inner exception is:

TypeLoadException: Requested Windows Runtime type "WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent1.WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent" is not registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designer can't initialize WinRT (COM) objects. You'll have to use the [DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesigntool%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to prevent your WinRT objects being instantiated while in design mode.

Comment: but the same case works fine in WinRT, but it doesn't in Windows Phone

Comment: Different team/division, different designer.